# Effective way to migrate from SQL Server to MySQL

Tags: sql-server, mysql, migration

I have a 20GB Microsoft SQL Server database that needs to be migrated to MySQL.

Right now I only have the schema for the source db. I tried the migration wizard on the schema in MySQL Workbench and it worked out fine (with some minor varchar issues that was easily solved)

As I am waiting for the data I am wondering if MySQL Workbench is the way to go here as the source is 20GB.

Can the Workbench handle it? Is it effective?
Should I investigate other tools than the Workbench?

Any advice and pointers is appreciated.

Comment: Presumably this is a one-time event?  Why not just wait for it, and see if it works?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for an easy-to-use, open-sourced tool, checkout [etlalchemy](https://github.com/seanharr11/etlalchemy).

You can carry out your SQL Server to MySQL database migration with 4 lines of Python code:

**To Install**:

```
pip install etlalchemy
```

(On El Capitan you may have to run `pip install --ignore-installed etlalchemy`)

**To Run**:

```py
from etlalchemy import ETLAlchemySource, ETLAlchemyTarget

mssql_db_source = ETLAlchemySource("mssql+pyodbc://username:password@DSN_NAME")

mysql_db_target = ETLAlchemyTarget("mysql://username:password@hostname/db_name", 
              drop_database=True)

mysql_db_target.addSource(mssql_db_source)
mysql_db_target.migrate()
```

If you want to learn more about etlalchemy, check out [this article](http://thelaziestprogrammer.com/sharrington/databases/migrating-between-databases-with-etlalchemy).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench provides a quick way to migrate data and applications from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL with fastest possible ways utilizing resources.20 GB data is not a big deal.There are tools available in the market but which is not free of cost.

Comment: Well it didn't work for me. Kept displaying errors in data in a poorly laid and jumbled up error messages.  After wasting several days, finally tried a paid tool and it worked fine.